# React: Using state as index of array of object gives undefined even after checking

Tags: reactjs

I have a state and use it as index of array of objects. And When I pass that object into other components as props. It gives an Error even though there's checking:

```
import React, { Dispatch, useState } from 'react';

import { TestingTwo } from './TestingTwo';

interface Menu {
  ItemNumber?: number;
  ItemString?: string;
  setState?: Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>;
}

export const TestingPage = () => {
  const [activeMenu, setActiveMenu] = useState<number>(1);
  const [something, SetSomething] = useState<number>(0);
  const TestMenu: Menu[] = [
    {
      ItemNumber: 1,
      ItemString: 'test',
      setState: SetSomething,
    },
  ];
  return (
    <>
      {TestMenu && TestMenu[activeMenu] && TestMenu[activeMenu].ItemNumber ? (
        <TestingTwo
          number={TestMenu[activeMenu].ItemNumber || 0}

          OnClick={() => TestMenu[activeMenu].setState(1)}
//Cannot Invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'

        />
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
};
```

The component:

```
interface TestingTwoProps {
  number: number;
  OnClick: () => void;
}

export const TestingTwo = ({ number, OnClick }: TestingTwoProps) => {
  return <>{number}</>;
};
```

[image]

Comment: `TestMenu[activeMenu].ItemNumber || 0`

Comment: @Konrad how can we do the same thing when we are trying to invoke functions in the object? I've updated the question

Answer (score 1):

There's three solutions here:

1. Update the type of number in `TestingTwo` to number | undefined.
2. The other solution is:

   <TestingTwo number={TestMenu[activeMenu].ItemNumber ?? 0} />
3. (Recommended if you know number will always be required) update your interface from:

   `interface Menu { ItemNumber?: number; ItemString?: string; }`
   to:

   `interface Menu { ItemNumber: number; ItemString?: string; }`

Removing the optional `?` on ItemNumber

*UPDATE FOR SECOND QUESTION*

You have the same issue on set state where the interface has it as an optional field.

1. You make it required by removing the `?`
2. `OnClick={() => TestMenu[activeMenu]?.setState()` < update to that where you have a question mark checking if setState exists

*FINAL EDIT*

To get the final bit you need just add the following:

`OnClick={() => TestMenu[activeMenu]?.setState(1)`

The reason for you error is you were not passing a value to setState

Comment: This could work, but how can we do the same thing when we are trying to invoke functions in the object? I'll update the question.

Comment: You have the same issue on set state where the interface has it as an optional field.

1. You make it required by removing the `?`
2. OnClick={() => TestMenu[activeMenu]?.setState() < update to that where you have a question mark checking if setState exists

Comment: @lamsmallsmall have updated my answer

Comment: Yes, I intentionally has it as optional field. Is there anyway to work around it while keeping the setState as optional?

Comment: @lamsmallsmall yes - if you look at option two in my answer now (after the UPDATE FOR SECOND QUESTION)

Comment: It still gives the same error

Comment: can you show me the code you have now?

Comment: `OnClick={() => TestMenu[activeMenu]?.setState()}`
I only added a question mark after [activeMenu]

Comment: @lamsmallsmall are you sure its not erroring now because you aren't passing a value into setState? add a 1 or something into set state (keep the `?`) and let me know if the error is gone

Answer (score -1):

I have found a workaround for this. But I don't understand why do I have to use a tempFunc to store the setState function first. Can anyone kindly explain to me?

```
<>
      {TestMenu && TestMenu[activeMenu] && TestMenu[activeMenu].ItemNumber ? (
        <TestingTwo
          number={TestMenu[activeMenu].ItemNumber || 0}
          OnClick={() => {
            const tempFunc = TestMenu[activeMenu]?.setState;
            if (tempFunc) {
              tempFunc(1);
            }
          }}
        />
      ) : null}
    </>
```

Comment: See my answer above (after FINAL EDIT) for a much cleaner solution to this

Comment: @Jm3s I have tried it, still same error